# How to find the Cognito Pool Id

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I am trying the `DynamoDBSample` found [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/DynamoDBObjectMapper-Sample/Objective-C/DynamoDBSample).

The problem is that I need to configure the following attributes in the plist as shown below. However, I am not sure of the value of `PoolId` and how to obtain it. Can someone direct me to find the `PoolId`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup a Cognito identity pool using [Cognito Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/federated). After setting up the pool you will find the Cognito identity pool id.
You can find the details related to identity pool setup in the [Cognito developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html).

Answer (score 2):

As Vinay touched on, when you create an identity pool via the Cognito console, it will be listed in the sample code that is generated for you. This sample code can be viewed again from the 'Sample code' tab once you click on the pool in question from the Cognito console. Further, the pool id is listed in the URL once you have clicked into the pool from the Cognito console.

If you have not created an identity pool, follow the link Vinay's answer had to the Cognito console to do so.